# System reflection IL emit override method syntax

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'd like to properly override ToString() in the generated code below. My ToString should return the content of the _value field.

I'm having difficulty finding the syntax to correctly override it - here's my current code:

```
static public Type BuildType() {
    AppDomain domain = Thread.GetDomain();
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName {Name = "DynamicDataGridDataAsm"};
    AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName,AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
    ModuleBuilder dynamicDataGridDataModule = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicDataGridDataModule", "DynamicDataGridDataModule.dll");
    TypeBuilder ivTypeBld = dynamicDataGridDataModule.DefineType("DynamicDataGridData", TypeAttributes.Public);

    FieldBuilder field = ivTypeBld.DefineField("_value", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Public);
    MethodBuilder getValue = ivTypeBld.DefineMethod("ToString", 
        MethodAttributes.Public ,
        CallingConventions.Standard,
        typeof(string), 
        Type.EmptyTypes);

    ILGenerator il = getValue.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return ivTypeBld.CreateType();
}
```

I'm currently invoking this method explicitly on the object but I'm assuming that if I override it correctly then I (and the framework) can call it with the dot operator and execute my implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading some more and looking at additional examples, these parameters and calls appear to properly override the ToString() method of object:

```
    FieldBuilder field = ivTypeBld.DefineField("_value", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Public);
    MethodBuilder toStringMethod = ivTypeBld.DefineMethod("ToString",
        MethodAttributes.Public
        | MethodAttributes.HideBySig
        | MethodAttributes.NewSlot
        | MethodAttributes.Virtual
        | MethodAttributes.Final,
        CallingConventions.HasThis,
        typeof(string), 
        Type.EmptyTypes);

    ILGenerator il = toStringMethod.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    ivTypeBld.DefineMethodOverride(toStringMethod, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
```

Better info is available but to assist anyone who's looking, the attributes dictate that the new function be public, hide base class member by the name and signature, occupy a new vtable slot, be final and will be called on an instance (is not a static function - HasThis).

I haven't looked into if or why 'NewSlot' is necessary or really what it means to this method definition.